# Insert a number into the sorted array and arrange the order

Tags: c

I have written a C language program, but the result is not satisfactory. The output result is:

```
0  20  22  23  24  25  26   0   0   0
```

Code show as below

```
int a[10] = {20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26}, i, t, n;
for(i=6, a[6] == 21; a[i] <a[i-1] && i > 0; i--)
{
    t = a[i];
    a[i] = a[i-1];
    a[i-1] = t;
}
for(n = 0; n < 10; n++)
    printf("%4d",a[n]);
printf("\n");
return 0;
```

Comment: The loop should be  `for(i=6, a[6]=21; i>0 && a[i]<a[i-1]; i--)`.  Note that `a[6]==21` is not correct because `==` should be `=`

Comment: The code should track the actual number of elements which are assigned a value in that array. It has a *capacity* of 10, but only the first 6 elements are explicitly initialized, the compiler will set the extra zeroes.

Comment: The goal is not clear. What is the expected output? If there is enough room in the array, you can shift everything after `20` to the right, then assign `arr[2] = 21`. It doesn't need rearranging after that. Or insert the number after `26`, and sort again. Neither of these methods matches the description of the question.